# WordPress update_option() not working with a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a settings page for my WordPress plugin, and the update_option() method isn't working as expected.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $tt = $_POST['theme_title'];
    echo $tt;
    update_option('theme_title', $tt);
}
```

Using the code above, if I submit the form with a new value for `theme_title`, the page prints out the new value. `update_option()` even returns "1". But the new value isn't saved in the database.

However, replacing with `update_option('theme_title', 'test')` results in the value "test" being saved in the database.

How is it possible that the method only accepts an explicit string and not a variable?

Comment: Maybe you need to hook to [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook ? Create a function, with your code there, and hook it to `save_post` and see if it will work.

Comment: does `echo $tt` print string or array?

Comment: @PoX it prints string

Comment: @dingo_d But I'm not saving a post, so that function wouldn't be triggered.